# Run a script with an option parameter

Tags: linux, bash

I want to choose with option -d a directory which I want to back up in the home directory

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash-

date_created="backup-`date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M"`";
backup_directory_name=$date_created;
directory="backup/";

getopts d:t: option;

case $option in
    d)
            directory=$1;
    ;;

    t)
            backup_directory_name=$1;
    ;;
esac

cd ~;
tar cvpfz $backup_directory_name.tgz $directory;
```

It won't run when I use an option, I get following fault:

tar: You may not specify more than one `-Acdtrux` or `--test-label` option
Try `tar --help' or`tar --usage' for more information.

Comment: haven't used getopts recently but pretty sure $1 is just the first parameter to the whole script. You need $OPTARG or something similar to get the value of the parameter and you may need to shift() the args as well. It's all explained here: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial

Comment: I already found that link but I can't get it working :(

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to re-write it as a loop around `getopts()`:

```
while getopts "..." opt ; do
    case $opt in
    ...
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))
```

Comment: Doesn't getopts shift the option index automatically? I googled around and I'm finding contradictory results.

Comment: Not if you plan to use `$@` and `$*`.